# sql error SyntaxException preparedstatement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a PreparedStatement to execute a SQL query. Here is the Query.

```
select * from DEVICES WHERE device_id in (?,?,?,?)
```

Here is the error i am getting

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Here is the Stacktrace that captured. It looks like the error is occuring when I am executing the query (which is logical).

Here is the Stacktrace that captured. It looks like the error is occuring when I am executing the query (which is logical).

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2690)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1465)
at com.verizonwireless.digitalframe.PictureProcessor.getFilteredFrameList(PictureProcessor.java:715)
at com.verizonwireless.digitalframe.Main.processPictureModule(Main.java:141)
at com.verizonwireless.digitalframe.Main.processRequest(Main.java:78)
at com.verizonwireless.digitalframe.Main.doPost(Main.java:53)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man what a mistake...

I was using

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

I should have been using

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

I works now!